# How to write jasmine tests for function which are called from html template in angular

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have few functions which are defined in my ts file and those functions are being called from html template i am not getting how to write jasmine tests for those function which are getting called in html template so that in karma test coverage those methods will shown as covered below are these functions :

```
 public onPageSizeChanged() {
    this.gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize(Number(this.dataPerPage));
    setTimeout(() => this.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit(), 0);
  }

   private onReady(params) {
    this.api = params.api;
    this.api.setColumnDefs(this.columnDefs);
    this.api.setRowData(this.rowData);
    this.api.paginationSetPageSize(this.dataPerPage);
  }

   describe('onPageSizeChanged()', () => {
    it('onPageSizedChanged() Called', () => {
        component.dataPerPage = 25;
        component.onPageSizeChanged();
        expect(component.onPageSizeChanged).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(component.onPageSizeChanged).toHaveBeenCalledWith(component.dataPerPage);
    });
    beforeEach(() => {
        component.gridToolTip({
            startDate: 'Start Date', endDate: 'End Date', Address: '123 ABC',
            city: 'City Name'
        });
        component.columnDefs = [
            {
                headerName: `<span class="headerName"> Start Date </span>`,
                width: 100,
                field: 'startDate',
                headerTooltip: 'Start Date',
                cellFilter: 'date:\'MM/dd/yyyy\'',
                cellRenderer: this.gridToolTip
            },
            {
                headerName: `<span class="headerName"> End Date </span>`,
                width: 100,
                field: 'endDate',
                headerTooltip: 'End Date',
                cellRenderer: this.gridToolTip
            },
            {
                headerName: `<span class="headerName"> Address </span>`,
                width: 100,
                field: 'address',
                headerTooltip: 'Address',
                cellRenderer: this.gridToolTip
            }
            {
                headerName: `<span class="headerName"> City Name </span>`,
                width: 100,
                field: 'city',
                headerTooltip: 'City Name',
                cellRenderer: this.gridToolTip
            },

        ];
        component.createColumnDefs();
        component.createRowData();
        component.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
            columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs(),
            rowData: this.createRowData(),
            pagination: true,
            paginationPageSize: 25,
            enableColResize: true,
            rowHeight: 30,
            headerHeight: 30,
            paginationNumberFormatter: this.changePaginationNumberFormat
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-dom-testing?

Comment: May i know the reason of down voting this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general gist is:

1. Create TestBed
2. Create Component Instance
3. Call Method
4. Evaluate Results

So, lets review each step.  First create a TestBed.  You can do this in a beforeEach block:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports : [FormsModule, otherImports],
        declarations: [ MyComponent, MyOtherComponents, etc... ],
        providers : []
    })
});
```

Then create a component instance.  I'd also do this in a beforeEach()

```
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;
let comp: MyComponent;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
}));
```

Now call the method, and check the results:

```
describe('onPageSizeChanged()', function() {

    it('onPageSizedChanged() Called', function () {
        // set up defaults
        // comp.property = value;
        comp.dataPerPage = 100;
        comp.onPageSizeChanged();
        expect(comp.onPageSizeChanged).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(comp.onPageSizeChanged).toHaveBeenCalledWith(comp.dataPerPage);
        expect(comp.gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

It can be slightly more complex if you want to test the `gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit()` method since it is called in a timeout.  I think you'll have to make use of `fixture.detectChanges()` to trigger the timeout and `fixture.whenStable()` to run your tests when the changes are complete.  Generally like this:

```
        it('testTimerFunction', (done : DoneFn) => {
            comp.dataPerPage = 100;
            comp.onPageSizeChanged();
            fixture.detectChanges();
            fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
expect(fixture.componentInstance.gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit).toHaveBeenCalled();
                    done();
            });

        });
```

Your `onReady()` method is private and cannot be called from the unit tests--or from the HTML template code--so to test that you'll need to call a public method that calls it and then you can test the value changes on the api value.

Comment: JeffryHouser i am getting this error                                              
             TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 
            'this.gridOptions.api.paginationSetPageSize') in Karma.entry.js (line 81565)

Comment: That error usually means you're trying to drill down into a variable that is not yet defined. My code is just provided as a sample, and may need tweaks to work in your specific environment.

Comment: I defined gridOptions and calling createColumnDefs in beforEach but now i am getting error 'undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '_this.createColumnDefs()') in karma.entry.js

Comment: Without seeing more of your original code, I'm not sure.  gridOptions looks like a value inside your component, so you should not need to define it manually in your test unless your explicit purpose is to mock it.  If that is your purpose you can also mock sizeColumnsToFit().